# unicode hello world for C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to output things like 안, 蠀, ☃  from C

```
#include <wchar.h>
int main()
{
    fwprintf(stdout, L"안, 蠀, ☃\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output is ?, ?, ?

How do I print those characters?

Edit:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    fwprintf(stdout, L"안, 蠀, ☃\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this did the trick. output is 안, 蠀, ☃ . except that the chinese character and snowman appears as box in my urxvt probably because I did not enable those locales.

```
$ locale -a
C
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
ko_KR
ko_KR.euckr
ko_KR.utf8
korean
korean.euc
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
```

which locale do I have to enable additionally so that it'll display chinese character and snowman?  maybe do I need font?

will the above program work on Windows?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: damn, something is wrong with my computer because i see also those ? in the code sample!

Comment: Try setting your encoding to Unicode (UTF-8) (in Firefox, View->Character Encoding)

Comment: I see "ang" in Korean, "ci" in Chinese, and a snowman. That is not hello world in any of those languages.

Comment: Your edit (with the setlocale line) works for me on Mac OS X under Apple's Terminal.app as well as urxvt; I have LANG=en_US.UTF-8. It's possible that you don't have fonts installed that include the Chinese character and snowman.

Comment: utf8everywhere.org will teach you how to do text on windows.

Answer (score 9):

You have to set your output terminal as Unicode compatible.

On Linux (with Bash shell), try:

```
$ LANG=en.UTF-8
```

and also make sure that your terminal emulator can actually display Unicode and is configured to do so.

Answer (score 6):

There are many individual stages in the process of getting Unicode output - all of which must be correctly configured.

First, are you compiling with unicode support enabled?  you will need to do so under Windows (-D UNICODE -D __UNICODE).

Second, are you emitting to a command line which supports unicode, both in principle but also having a font containing the glyphs of the characters you are emitting?

Third, do the unicode encodings used by your compiler and your command line match?  it's no use having UCS2 in your binary when your command line expected UTF8.

You basically need to really understand Unicode and its encodings, to get this right.  Don't imagine it's straightforward or you don't need to learn all the underlying concepts; this stuff doesn't work by accident because there are too many things which have to be exactly correct.

Answer (score 4):

The C `wchar_t` is defined as:

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.1.1). [...]

The difference between multibyte characters and `wchar_t`:

> multibyte characters may require more than one byte for a given character depending on the encoding (e.g: UTF-8, UTF-16)

whereas

> `wchar_t` has a fixed size i.e. sizeof(wchar_t)  which is implementation defined. Note, that this width defines what encoding(s) your `wchar_t` can support. So, if `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` there's no way you'd be able to use UTF-32 encoding.

Also remember that `wchar_t` does not have a sense of encoding by itself. You'd first have to tell the compiler what sort of encoding it has to use for `wchar_t` data. The erroneous output is most probably because the characters are being treated in the default encoding which can't support those characters properly and a failed match leads to a 'notdef' style '?' output.

Comment: wchar_t is not necessarily multibyte - it can be one byte long.

Comment: Well yes, I should have been more pedantic :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your system to accept those characters. What are you using? Windows, Linux?

Comment: i'm using linux.

    $ locale
    all set to en_US.utf8

Answer (score 0):

Just as Alnitak suggested, one has to specify a locale with a character set/encoding that includes the characters you want to show.  (Unicode/)UTF-8 should cover all Unicode characters.

Your terminal should use a font that has respective glyphs.

Windows' CMD.EXE is notoriously weak when it comes to character sets beyond 8 bits.  Perhaps, you'd need a GUI pane instead of relying on stdout.