# How to write UTF-8 file with fprintf in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, mfc, fopen, printf

I am programming (just occassionally) in C++ with VisualStudio and MFC. I write a file with fopen and fprintf. The file should be encoded in UTF8. Is there any possibility to do this? Whatever I try, the file is either double byte unicode or ISO-8859-2 (latin2) encoded.

Glanebridge

Comment: See other posts about Unicode in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-in-c

Comment: You can try to see this thread

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543346/how-to-write-unicode-hello-world-in-c-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need Visual Studio 2005 or later. You can then call fopen with the parameters:

```
LPCTSTR strText = "абв";
FILE *f = fopen(pszFilePath, "w,ccs=UTF-8");
_ftprintf(f, _T("%s"),  (LPCTSTR) strText);
```

Keep in mind this is Microsoft extension, it probably won't work with gcc or other compilers.

Comment: I don't think this will affect data written to the file using fprintf.

Comment: You need to use _ftprintf. See the changes in my answer.

Comment: Or simply use fwprintf. What's going on is that `ccs=UTF-8` sets the _O_U8TEXT  mode on the file, so that writing wide characters to the file will cause UTF-8 to be output. Writing narrow characters with this mode set will result in an error.

Comment: Do you mean that you already have a buffer with UTF-8 text? In that case why not just open the file in binary mode and write the buffer to it with fwrite?

Comment: No, I mean that since using tprintf will only work here if TCHAR and all the T functions resolve to wchar_t functions why not just use the wchar_t functions directly? TCHAR is only useful when a program is actually going to switch between char and wchar_t. If you don't want to use both then there's no reason to use TCHAR. `FILE* f = fopen(filename,"w,css=UTF-8"); fwprintf(f,L"%s",L"абв");`

Comment: Oops, I had somehow decided you were the OP, sorry. As for fwprintf, you're right, it's better to use fwprintf.

Comment: I checked and that one really works! (Visual Studio 2013). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to set your locale or set any special modes on the file if you just want to use fprintf. You simply have to use UTF-8 encoded strings.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;
    std::string utf8_string = convert.to_bytes(L"кошка 日本国");

    if(FILE *f = fopen("tmp","w"))
        fprintf(f,"%s\n",utf8_string.c_str());
}
```

Save the program as UTF-8 with signature or UTF-16 (i.e. don't use UTF-8 without signature, otherwise VS won't produce the right string literal). The file written by the program will contain the UTF-8 version of that string. Or you can do:

```
int main() {
    if(FILE *f = fopen("tmp","w"))
        fprintf(f,"%s\n","кошка 日本国");
}
```

In this case you must save the file as UTF-8 *without* signature, because you want the compiler to think the source encoding is the same as the execution encoding... This is a bit of a hack that relies on the compiler's, IMO, broken behavior.

You can do basically the same thing with any of the other APIs for writing narrow characters to a file, but note that none of these methods work for writing UTF-8 to the Windows console. Because the C runtime and/or the console is a bit broken you can only write UTF-8 directly to the console by doing SetConsoleOutputCP(65001) and then using one of the `puts` variety of function.

If you want to use wide characters instead of narrow characters then locale based methods and setting modes on file descriptors could come into play.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main() {
    if(FILE *f = fopen("tmp","w")) {
        _setmode(_fileno(f), _O_U8TEXT);
        fwprintf(f,L"%s\n",L"кошка 日本国");
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    if(auto f = std::wofstream("tmp")) {
        f.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(),
                new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>)); // assumes wchar_t is UTF-16
        f << L"кошка 日本国\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @NicolBolas The first example uses wstring_convert from C++11, but any other method of obtaining a UTF-8 encoding works too, e.g. WideCharToMultiByte. The last example uses a C++11 codecvt facet for which there's not a built-in, pre-c++11 replacement. The other two examples don't use C++11.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should simply set a locale which uses UTF-8 as external encoding.  My understanding -- I'm not a Windows programmer -- is that [Windows has no such locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324542/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-for-en-us-utf-8-locale), so you have to resort to implementation specific means or non [standard libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-in-c) (link from Dave's comment).